# Adding a vignette stops devtools::check() from working

Tags: r, devtools, vignette

I've been writing a personal package with reference to [Hadley's guide](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/intro.html). However, adding a minimal vignette using `devtools::use_vignette()` seems to break `devtools::check()`.

When I try to run `check()` I get one error:

```
file 'C:/path/temp/package/DESCRIPTION' is not in valid DCF format
```

and one warning:

```
In read.dcf(dfile, keep.white = .keep_white_description_fields) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/path/temp/package/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'Permission denied'
```

I can successfully run `devtools::check()` if I delete the vignettes folder and `devtools::build_vignettes()` runs ok.

**Edited to add:**
I wondered if this was an issue with trying run check from a network location, but I copied the project to `C:\R\package_name` and it still returns the same error.

Curiously, this does appear to be machine dependent as I get the above error on my work machine, but not on my personal laptop. Work machine is win7, personal win10.

DESCRIPTION is copied below

```
Package: pkg_nm
Type: Package
Title: A title
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("name", "name", email = "emal@email.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: Functions for working with data from my source.
License: OGL
LazyData: TRUE
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
URL: [url here]
BugReports: [url here]
Imports:
    lubridate,
    stringr,
    dplyr,
    lazyeval,
    magrittr
Collate:
    'my_function.R'
Suggests: knitr,
    rmarkdown
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

Comment: What is the error message when you do `read.dcf(file = "DESCRIPTION")`?

Comment: There is no error message when I do `read.dcf()`. It prints the contents of the DCF to the console.

Comment: However, if I try to do `read.dcf()` on the tempfile location returned in the error above I get:
`Error in read.dcf(file = "C:/Users/r.bot/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcLoGrg/Rbuild1f4069c1632e/package/DESCRIPTION") : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In read.dcf(file = "C:/Users/r.bot/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcLoGrg/Rbuild1f4069c1632e/package/DESCRIPTION") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/r.bot/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcLoGrg/Rbuild1f4069c1632e/package/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'`

Comment: I see RoxygenNote 5.0.1, but we're at 6.0.1 now. Did you try to first update `roxygen2` and `devtools`? I've noticed before that when you have conflicting versions of these packages, they don't always work nicely together. It might be that either devtools or roxygen2 messes up the DESCRIPTION file when building the vignettes.

Comment: @JorisMeys thanks, I've updated both to the latest cran versions and get the same error message. 
I can't do `library(devtools)
build_github_devtools()

#### Restart R before continuing ####
install.packages("devtools.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")` as described here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/README.html beacuse I'm stuck behind a corporate firewall.

Comment: @r.bot the latest CRAN versions should be OK.

Comment: @JorisMeys, thanks, so it's not that then.